# Convert ndarray to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to just get the unique values of a pandas column into a new pandas dataframe as such:

```
res = df.resolution.unique()
a = pd.DataFrame()
a['Unique Resolution Types'] = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

I tried converting res into a list but still the same error. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why not `pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Unique...'])`?

Comment: No problem @Snorrlaxxx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct to write pd.Dataframe(res);

```
res = df.resolution.unique()
a = pd.DataFrame()
a['Unique Resolution Types'] = res
```

Now, it will work.

Comment: 'a' is already a dataframe. You fill in the 'a' dataframe with res.

Comment: `a = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['Unique...'])` is correct.

Comment: For code block in comments use tilde i.e. `\`` .Cheers good day mate. ;)